# Where the folder of new symbol saved in the computer ?- QGIS 2.12

Tags: symbology, qgis-2.12

I created new polygon symbol called "476" and saved it in the Layer properties in one computer (with the "save" button under the symbology ):

[image]
[image]

I seeking the symbology folder where this new symbol saved in, in order to work with it in other computer.

I know the option of save it as qml file and prefer not to use it- Is there a folder that i can copy\paste to other computer?

Answer (score 2):

All the symbologies are saved in the `symbology-ng-style` db file found in the .qgis2 folder. 
You can send that file to any computer, and place it in the .qgis2 folder path and it should give you all the symbologies you've created